# LyX - export with custom document class [Linux]

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I have a document written in lyx, which is supposed to be exported to pdf file on Linux. I write it on Windows, but then I commit the .lyx file to repository and it's suposed to be exported to PDF on another machine with Ubuntu.

I'm using the following line to export file:

```
lyx -batch --export-to pdf2 ./out/MasterThesis.pdf ./Docs/Thesis/src/RestTestingFramework.lyx
```

In the `src` directory I have `.cls` and `.sty` files with my custom document class  and on linux I have a copy of that in `~/.lyx/layouts/`.
On Windows everything works fine, but on linux I get following errors:

```
LayoutFile.cpp (332): Existing textclass dcsbook is redefined by /home/travis/build/matjanos/MasterThesis/Docs/Thesis/src/dcsbook.layout
LayoutModuleList.cpp (253): Default module dcs added although it is unavailable and can't check requirements.
```

Where is the mistake?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you try removing the `-batch` option? I don't think it's useful in this case and might actually mess something up. Also, is your Ubuntu installation a headless server or can you run the GUI? If so, can you export from the GUI without problems or do you see the same message?

Comment: Removing `-batch` doesn't change anything.
GUI version gives me some syntax errors, which, as I assume, arise because of incorrect layout configuration.
First error:
\section{Chapter Name}
                        
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined

Comment: Can you post a minimal example? for more information, see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: When I was preparing minimal example, I came across the essential problem... Everything works fine when I delete sections from my file. On Linux it seems to be undefined:
`\begin_layout Section` - this line causes the error mentioned in my previous comment.
Minimal example http://pastebin.com/cv652VyE

Comment: You need a file `dcsbook.layout`. You also need the necessary LaTeX files. You can copy them from your Windows computer to your Ubuntu computer or you can get them from here perhaps: https://github.com/politechnika/put-latex/tree/master/templates/dcs . If you're not sure how to install new LaTeX files, search for how to install LaTeX packages on Ubuntu and also LyX layout file (just need to put it in `~/.lyx/layouts` and then go to Tools > Reconfigure and restart LyX).

Comment: Thank you! I followed your tips, errors disappeared, but it didn't help. Nevertheless I managed to solve the problem. My command had `pdf2` as an export method, while the method used by GUI was `pdflatex`. I changed the command and everything is okey now!

Comment: Glad that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need a file dcsbook.layout. You also need the necessary LaTeX files. You can copy them from your Windows computer to your Ubuntu computer or you can get them from [here](http://github.com/politechnika/put-latex/tree/master/templates/dcs). Once you install the new LaTeX files, put the layout file in ~/.lyx/layouts and then go to Tools > Reconfigure and restart LyX.